# Conditions on the log partition of exponential family generating cumulants

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

Is any minimality condition of the parameterization required such that the derivative of the log partition function is equal to the mean?

The pdf of an exponential family distribution is given by $$p(x; \theta) = \exp \left( \sum_{i=1}^s \theta_i T_i(x) - A(\theta) \right) h(x),$$ where $$A(\theta) = \log \left( \int \exp \left( \sum_{i=1}^s \theta_i T_i(x) \right) h(x) dx \right).$$ Under some regularity conditions, $$\frac{\partial A(\theta)}{\partial \theta_i} = \frac{\displaystyle\int T_i(x) \exp \left( \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^s \theta_i T_i(x) \right) h(x) dx}{\displaystyle\int \exp \left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^s \theta_i T_i(x) \right) h(x) dx} = \mathbb{E} [T_i(X)].$$

Here is a motivating example to demonstrate the question:

For the Bernoulli distribution, we can re-write the pdf as an exponential family $p(x; \theta) = {n \choose x} \exp \left( x \log \frac{p}{1-p} + n \log (1-p) \right)$. Here, if we set $\theta = \log \frac{p}{1-p}$ and $T(x) = x$, $\frac{\partial A(\theta)}{\partial \theta} = \mathbb{E} [T(X)] = np$ as desired. However, this does not work if the parameters are not minimal. In an alternate parametrization, let $\theta_1 = \log p$, $\theta_2 = - \log (1-p)$, and $T_1(x) = T_2(x) = x$. Here, the derivative of the log partition does not seem to give us the mean: $\frac{\partial A(\theta)}{\partial \theta_1} = \frac{np}{1-p} \neq \mathbb{E} [T_1(X)] = np$ and $\frac{\partial A(\theta)}{\partial \theta_2} = n \neq \mathbb{E} [T_2(X)] = np$.

What are the general conditions required for $\frac{\partial A(\theta)}{\partial \theta_i} = \mathbb{E} [T_i(X)]$? Any reference is appreciated.